# How do I correctly destruct a derived object that was constructed using placement new

Tags: c++, embedded

Say we have a C++ program with this sort of class inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
   virtual ~A() {/* ... */}
};

class B : public A {
public:
   virtual ~B() {/* ... */}
};

class C : public A {
public:
   virtual ~C() {/* ... */}
};
```

And furthermore, there are specialized memory constraints which requires that B and C must always be allocated in a special region of RAM (e.g. a reserved region of physical SRAM that guarantees faster response times than normal SDRAM) and so we must never allocate instances of B or C from the general heap. So we might have something like:

```
A * ptr;

if(condition) {
   ptr = specialized_allocator(sizeof(B));
   new(ptr) B;
} else {
   ptr = specialized_allocator(sizeof(C));
   new(ptr) C;
}

/* Do something, which persists beyond the scope
   of the function where allocation occurred... */

ptr->~A();
specialized_deallocator(ptr);
```

In this scenario, will the complete chain of derived class destructors be invoked correctly, or will it end up only invoking the top-level A destructor?

Comment: `~A()` is `virtual`, you are fine.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new

Comment: Note that you can also provide your own `operator new()` & `operator delete()` implementations at the class level - that way you can use normal `new` & `delete` and it also becomes impossible to accidentally allocate those classes on the default heap. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/75EKv3ojo)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I'd looked at that reference material before I posted my question; I suppose it threw me off because it was only talking about calling a destructor via a pointer to a class of the exact same type, rather than a base-class pointer to a derived class.

Ultimately, the part that had thrown me for a loop was the fact that the chaining of virtual destructors would be preserved even if the base class destructor was being called explicitly by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this and it may help a little:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual ~B() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    virtual ~C() { std::cout << "C\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A* ptr = new C(); // or A* ptr = new B()
    // ...
    ptr->~A();
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling the destructor explicitly on a pointer created with `new`, use `delete` for that. Calling the destructor explicity should only be done when using `placement-new`, in which case a more meaningful example would look like this: `char buffer[sizeof(C)]; A *ptr = new(buffer) C; ... ptr->~A();`